# Como recorrer una clase dentro de otra

Tags: java, webservice

Me estoy topando con un problema debido a que tengo que recuperar la información de varias entidades que está en un servidor y guardarlas en tablas locales. Parto de una tabla principal que se llama Apunte.

***De modo gráfico sería lo siguiente:***

```
Tabla Apunte:
    - Tienes sus atributos...
      ***@OneToMany
      Formulario**
```

- Tabla Formulario:
  Titulo...
  @OneToMany
  Apuntes
  @ManyToOne
  List...
  @ManyToOne
  List...
- Tabla Seccion:
  Titulo
  @ManytoOne
  List...
- Tabla Campo:
  Nombre
  Valor

Mi primer problema es que no se como enfocar la recogida de las tablas "Campo, Seccion y formulario" que contiene realación entre ellas, ya que un un formulario tiene una lista de las tablas seccion y campo, a su vez seccion contiene una lista de campo.

Tengo pensado anidar varios bucles for ya que hay dependencias de una tabla a otra pero no se como enfocarlo mejor, si empezar desde el apunte y llegar a la tabla campo :

```
for (Apunte apunte : resultado.getApuntes())
// Aquí recorro la clase apunte y voy recogiendo sus valores para ir poblando mi tabla

apunte.setValores(apuntes.getValores())
apunte.setNombre(apuntes.getNombre())

// Una vez que recorro el apunte debo entrar dentro del formulario para recorredlo y obtener sus valores que a su vez contiene la dependencia a las otras 2 entidades.
For(Campo campo : apunte.getFormulario().getCampos())
 // creó una nueva instancia a campo y guardó los valores 
Campo campos = new Campo();
Campos.setApellido(campo.getApellido());
```

Mi duda viene aquí, que no sé si estoy enfocando bien el problema o debo de recorre las clases en otro sentido.

Comment: [Te pueden votar negativamente porque sin código, es difícil ayudarte](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2875/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disculpar si no me he podido expresar bien en la pregunta, pero ya conseguí hacer lo que necesitaba. Era tan simple como lo que expongo aquí, espero que le ayude en un futuro a gente que este consultando servicios soap y pretenda descarga algo para guardarlo en una BD en local.

Primero recorro la tabla Apunte y voy guardando sus campos dentro de los campos que tiene mi entidad.

```
for (Apunte apunte : resultado.getApuntes()) {
// Creamos nuevo Apunte en el cual ire inyectando los get.
Apunte apuntes = new Apunte();

apuntes.setRegistro(apunte.getRegistro());                  
apuntes.setHora(apunte.getHora());          
apuntes.setNombre(apunte.getNombre());
apuntes.setApellido(apunte.getApellido());

// Luego cuando llego al campo Intersado necesito nuevamente recorrer un for para recoger todos sus atributos y poder guardarlos en la tabla de la BD correspondiente. Cabe matizar que este for se recorrera dentro de apunte.getInteresado().

for (Interesado interesados : apunte.getInteresados()) {

// Creamos nuevo Interesado
Interesado interesado = new Interesado();
                                
interesado.setIdentificador(interesados.getIdentificador());
interesado.setInteresado(interesados.getInteresado());
interesado.setNombreInteresado(interesados.getNombreInteresado());

// Posteriormente guardare el interesado llamando a mi servicio.
servicioClientes.saveInteresado(interesado);
}
```

Luego llego al Formulario el cual solo contiene 1 apunte, (1 a 1).

```
Formulario formulario = new FormularioType();

formulario.setTitulo(apunte.getFormulario().getTitulo());
formulario.setPlazos(apunte.getPlazos());

// Nuevamente guardo el formulario. 
servicioClientes.saveFormulario(formulario);

// Por último guardo el apunte.
servicioClientes.saveApunte(apunte);
```

Con esto ya estaría todo, espero que les ayude en un futuro a alguien que tuviese el mismo problema que he tenido yo.